# How to make ImageView invisible when using ImageLoader (novoda)

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-loading

In my current project I'm using [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader). I would like to know if it is possible to make `ImageView` invisible when error ocurres or image doesn't exist on server? If so, how to do it? Now I'm using default image (`setDefaultImageResId`).

EDIT:

I know how to make `View` invisibe. I want to know how can I do it with ImageLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no direct way but you can set the error image to an empty drawable

```
imageTagFactory.setErrorImageId(android.R.color.transparent);
```